# AWS Code deploy using image from docker hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, dockerhub

I have created an AWS Codepipeline which is triggered when a new image is pushed into ECR and it deploys the application on to our ECS cluster.

Now I want to do the same but get the image from docker hub and not from Amazon ECR. Is it possible? I haven't been able to find any solution for it. And if it is possible can some one please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Bump! I'd like to know this too! I prefer to keep all my open source containers in Dockerhub where they are visible.

Comment: According to [How to Use Docker Images from a Private Registry for Your Build Environment](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/how-to-use-docker-images-from-a-private-registry-in-aws-codebuild-for-your-build-environment/) It looks like it potentially does. I need to do some more fiddling to find out for sure but will add an answer when I know more.